# Syntax error in FROM Clause Da.fill?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dataadapter

I'm Getting a syntax error in the form clause in this code, can anyone help? Thanks :)

```
    Dim sql As String                                  
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection                
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter                    
    Dim ds As New DataSet                               



    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = G:\school\Thespellingbee\Resources\Spelling Bee1.mdb"   
    con.Open()                                          

    sql = "SELECT * FROM Words + Definitions"

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)          

    da.Fill(ds, "Words + Definitions")                  
    con.Close()                                         


    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)         stored data adapter in the variable cb
    WordTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Words + Definitions").Rows(0).Item(2)
    DescriptionTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Words + Definitions").Rows(0).Item(3)

    da.Update(ds, "Words + Definitions")

    MsgBox("It's working", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
```

This is me trying to update the database using a dataset and adapter, im still fairly new to v basic as i have just started learning it in A-level.

Comment: Words + Definitions, what are words and Definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your this line is creating a problem:-

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Words + Definitions"
```

I dont think that this is allowed. You cannot join tables using +(considering Words and Definitions as tables)

And if the table name is Words + Definitions the you may try this:-

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Words + Definitions]"
```

Also this line should be changes from

```
da.Fill(ds, "Words + Definitions")
```

to simple this:-

```
da.Fill(ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table is named "Words + Definitions", then you need to put it in square brackets in your `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM [Words + Definitions]
```